# Specifying level for each value of a column in a data frame

Tags: r

My question is simple but somehow I can`t figure it out.

I have an increasing numeric vector in which values are not unique.

```
a <- c(1,2,4,4,7,7,7,9,12,25,25,26)
```

I want to create another column b which will give me the corresponding level of each of the element of vector a. Here, b is:

```
b <- c(1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,8)
```

Can someone please help me how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
as.integer(factor(a))
```

Or this is probably better:

```
match(a, unique(a))
```

Comment: I think the `factor` version is really neat.

Comment: Thank you @MadScone. It also answered my follow-up question.. :)

Answer (score 1):

use `cumsum` and `diff`,hope it help,thanks.

```
b=cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(a)!=0))
 b
 [1] 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
findInterval(a, unique(a))
#[1] 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 8
```